# Getting Null (passing data between ViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, string

I just created a NSString variable in SBSettingsViewController and I want to get it in my SBViewController.

I know.. there's a lot of responses about this, but i really don't know what i'm doing wrong. I'm just getting a (null) value using this.

Thanks!

SBViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SBViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *gameMode;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *gameMode;

- (IBAction)geraManobra;
```

SBViewController.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SBViewController.h"
#import "SBSettingsViewController.h"

@interface SBViewController ()

@end

@implementation SBViewController

@synthesize gameMode;

- (IBAction)geraManobra {
    NSLog(@" %@",gameMode);
}
```

SBSettingsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface SBSettingsViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction)selectModeFlat;
```

SBSettingsViewController.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SBSettingsViewController.h"
#import "SBViewController.h"

@interface SBSettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SBSettingsViewController

- (IBAction)selectModeFlat {
    SBViewController *sbView = [[SBViewController alloc] init];
    sbView.gameMode = @"Flat Ground";
    NSLog(@" %@",sbView.gameMode);
}
```

Comment: I guess you do not need to write empty interface definition in implementation file

Comment: Roozbeh it is not the problem. it is generated by xcode in latest versions..

Comment: Where are you getting the null value?

Comment: Note that `sbView` is a local variable, and the object it addresses will be released as soon as it passes out of scope.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm getting (null) here: 

- (IBAction)geraManobra {
NSLog(@" %@",gameMode);
}

Comment: I guess you have two different objects of `SBViewController` class - one you create in `selectModeFlat` (and in this one you set the property), and you are executing `geraManobra` from the second one (in which no one set this property, so it's null).

Comment: so instead of creating new `SBViewController` you should pass a reference of the exsisting to `SBSettingsViewController` and set a property there.

Comment: Please update your code to show where and how do you call `geraManobra` method.

Comment: I call `geraManobra` pressing a button. in `SBViewController`

Comment: how do you switch between `SBViewController` and `SBSettingsViewController`?

Comment: I'm using storyborad and TabBar .... @MarkPervovskiy here i think you gonna understand better http://cl.ly/KYDA

Comment: Bruno, ***of course*** you're getting null there.  Your setting of `gameMode` never escapes from `selectModeFlat`, because `sbView` is a ***local variable***.

Comment: Ok, so how can i adjust this... because i saw a lot of tutorials and responses from here and looks like everyone do the same as i did...

Comment: If you create an instance of an class over here and set some values into it, then create a second instance over there, the values in the first object aren't magically transported from here to there.  If you're over there and you want to access the values in the first object you must somehow pass a pointer to that object from here to there.

Comment: (And especially the values won't get from here to there if the object you create here you immediately throw away.  Do you understand what a "local variable" is?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your SBSettingsViewController can be created before SBViewController, so, may be it is a good idea to move your property to application delegate and access with something like that

```
MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.gameMode = @"Something";
```

Anyway, I think you will need something more reliable to make it work, something like an object with your game settings accessible from your controllers. But I guess app delegate property is enough for the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to create a property

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) SBViewController *sbViewController;
```

in `SBSettingsViewController`, initialize it with your exsisting SBViewController object  somewhere inside your TabBarController, and then in your `selectModeFlat` you will be able to set its property `gameMode` with something like

```
self.sbViewController.gameMode = @"Something"
```

Comment: sorry but didn't work...still get the null value. check this out
.. its what I'm trying to do http://cl.ly/KYc6

Comment: As far as I understand, your `SBSettingsViewController` can be created before `SBViewController`, so, may be it is a good idea to move your property to application delegate and access with something like that `MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; appDelegate.gameMode = @"Something";`

Comment: Thanks @MarkPervovskiy ... it works perfect with this solution. if you want you can write a response and then I check it right! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following method has NO effect (other than to waste time):

```
- (IBAction)selectModeFlat {
    SBViewController *sbView = [[SBViewController alloc] init];
    sbView.gameMode = @"Flat Ground";
    NSLog(@" %@",sbView.gameMode);
}
```

The reason for this is that `sbView` is a local variable -- it's scope is only until the end of the method.  ARC will delete the created SBViewController when it gets to the closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)selectModeFlat {
    SBViewController *sbView = [[SBViewController alloc] init];
    sbView.gameMode = @"Flat Ground";
    NSLog(@" %@",sbView.gameMode);
}
```

it create  SBViewController newly,SBViewController run before SBSettingsViewController,you call action after creating "sbView"

```
- (IBAction)selectModeFlat {
    SBViewController *sbView = [[SBViewController alloc] init];
    sbView.gameMode = @"Flat Ground";
   [self sbView.geraManobra];
}
```

it recall the "geraManobra" action